# How to create a group via group relations?

Tags: group-theory

I have a group described by group relations. For simplicity group has a presentation $<a | a^n = e>$. How can I create this group in Mathematica?

Comment: Would `CyclicGroup[n]` do?

Comment: @Andrew no, I am looking for general solution for arbitrary group

Comment: You can't. Use GAP instead.

Comment: Is the group finite or not? How would you represent an infinite group in Mathematica?

Comment: @Somos yes, I suppose that group is finite

Answer (score 1):

Would something like

```
G := FormGroupoid[Range[0, 7], Mod[#1 + #2, 8] &]
```

work?

Comment: Thanks, but l'm looking for solution that uses group relations

Comment: `FormGroupoid` is not a builtin. If you are using a package, please mention it.